# How to fix intellij icons

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

I'm having a problem with my editor IntelliJ.

I't won't auto import anymore and it doesn't highlight red when something isn't possible also my icons sometimes disappear(class icons etc.).

[image]

[image]

I've tried to invalidate the caches and nothing happens..

Comment: Quit IDEA and remove the project files: `/.idea` directory inside your project - or if you are using the file based project format the `*.ipr`, `*.iws` etc. files. Then start IDEA again and import/open the project dir.

Comment: Done that, getting the same problems

Comment: strange... did you try and reinstall IDEA?

Comment: I've done that, but i wanted to keep my settings, had the same problem. I had some coding problems to do tonight so i kinda forced myself to fully reset my InteliJ, it is now fixed!